# vector persistent and transient in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, c++14

Can someone help me to understand this code?

What are `transient()` and `persistent()` doing here?

**Reference**:
CppCon 2017: Juan Pedro Bolivar Puente, "Postmodern immutable data structures"

**Time stamp**:
19:03

```cpp
vector<int> myitoa(vector<int> v, int first, int last)
{
    auto t = v.transient();
    for (auto i = first; i < last; ++i)
        t.push_back(i);
    return t.persistent();
}
```

[See the video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPhpelUfu8Q&t=19m3s)

Moreover, when I compiled it, I got an error:

> 'class std::vector' has no member named 'transient'

Any specific header file required?

Comment: I think this may be conceptual future code. Current `vector`s don't have a `transient` or `persistent` member method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vector` in this case is not `std::vector`, which has no `transient()` or `persistent()` methods, as the compiler error states.  It is actually an `immer::vector`, as Juan states at [18:06](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPhpelUfu8Q&t=18m06s):

> So, I'm using the `immer` namespace everywhere here. Nothing is `std` vector. This is an immutable vector ...

If you listen to the video carefully, Juan explains WHAT `transient()` and `persistent()` are actually doing, and WHY ([19:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPhpelUfu8Q&t=19m00s) - [25:58](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPhpelUfu8Q&t=25m58s)).

In a nutshell, the `vector` is immutable, its content can't be modified, so `transient()` makes a copy+write view of the `vector`. When the loop modifies the transient, a new copy of the `vector`'s data is made, which the loop can freely modify as needed.  And then `persistent()` makes a new immutable `vector` from the transient's data.

This is covered in some more details on [Transient Data Structures](https://clojure.org/reference/transients):

> Transient data structures are always created from an existing persistent ... data structure...
>
> You obtain a transient 'copy' of a data structure by calling `transient`. This creates a new transient data structure that is a copy of the source, and has the same performance characteristics. In fact, it mostly is the source data structure, and highlights the first feature of transients - creating one is O(1). It shares structure with its source, just as persistent copies share structure.
>
> The second feature of transients is that creating one does not modify the source, and the source cannot be modified via use of the transient. Your source data is immutable and persistent as always.
>
> ...
>
> When you are finished building up your results, you can create a persistent data structure by calling `persistent!` on the transient. This operation is also O(1). Subsequent to calling `persistent!`, the transient should not be used, and all operations will throw exceptions. This will be true also for any aliases you might have created.